# UI Wizard with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Have anyone used

http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example (Twitter Bootstrap Wizard Plugin with angularjs routing and controller

Can we use it to handle onPrevious and onNext with ng-click

$('#rootwizard').navigation error JavaScript.
How can I access index and navigation from within onNext and onPrevious

Example code.

```
nbf4_app.controller('modesController', function($scope, $http) 
{
    console.log("modesController");

    $scope.result = {};

    $scope.init = function()
    {
        $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) 
        {
            return false;
        }   
        });

    };

    $scope.onPrevious = function()
    {
        console.log("onPrevious");

        var $total = $('#rootwizard').navigation.find('li').length;
        var $current = $('#rootwizard').index+1;


        // If it's the last tab then hide the last button and show the finish instead
        if($current >= $total) 
        {
            $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').hide();
            $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').show();
            $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').removeClass('disabled');
        } 
        else 
        {
            $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').show();
            $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').hide();
        }
    };

    $scope.onNext = function()
    {
        console.log("onNext");

        var t = $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard.navigation;

        var $total = $('#rootwizard').navigation.find('li').length;
        var $current = $('#rootwizard').index+1;


        // If it's the last tab then hide the last button and show the finish instead
        if($current >= $total) 
        {
            $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').hide();
            $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').show();
            $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').removeClass('disabled');
        } 
        else 
        {
            $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').show();
            $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').hide();
        }
    };

    $scope.onFinish = function()
    {
      console.log("onFinish");


    };  

    $scope.init();

});
```

Thanks,
Naeem

Comment: OMG...don't use jQuery inside angular controller, that will messed up with angular digest cycle..

Comment: I donot think t mess thing unless you use same features together.